# How to concatenate in Python from .txt?

Tags: python-2.7, concatenation

I have a server.txt file where i have 3 names listed down:

```
server.txt
CFMPAPP1
CFMPAPP2
CFMPAPP3
```

i am looking to take these names by calling that server.txt file and want the output.txt file as mentioned below.

```
output.txt
CI_Name like  'CFMPAPP1%' or
CI_Name like  'CFMPAPP2%' or
CI_Name like  'CFMPAPP3%' or
```

Any Idea how to do this ?

Comment: Consider upvoting answers that helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done in three lines:

```py
with open('server.txt', 'r') as file:
  s = "".join(file.read())
  amended_string = "\n".join([ "CI_Name like '{}%' or".format(a) for a in  s.split('\n')])
```

And then you just need to save `amended_string` to `output.txt`. I hope that helps.

Comment: What is the benefit to holding all of the lines in memory?  Why not read/convert/write each line?

Comment: well, very good point! There is absolutely none, quite the opposite. Arguably, with a file 3 lines long there should be no practical difference and this solution is the first came to my mind

Comment: @maestromusica : i got the output **CI_Name like CFMPAPP1 or** however i am looking for **CI_Name like  'CFMPAPP1%' or**

Answer (score 0):

This solution only keeps one line at a time in memory:

```
with open('server.txt', 'r') as infile:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write("CI_Name like '{}%' or\n".format(line.rstrip()))
```